# Cache manifest causes $.getJSON to stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, offline-mode

I am developing a mobile app using HTML5, Javascript, jQuery Mobile, and offline storage.

I have a wep app that serves an array of JSON objects to the mobile app (on the same domain). It gets the JSON objects, stores them in a websql database then creates a unordered list with them which can be clicked...

The idea is that when the device is in offline mode I will pull the data from the offline database and bypass getting the JSON from the web app, then when the device is next online it can get a fresh copy of the data.

I've got to the part where I am creating my cache.manifest file. Basically it looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
index.html
app.html

NETWORK:
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js
js/data.js
js/script.js
```

However as soon as I add

```
<html  manifest="cache.manifest">
```

And reload the page my $.getJSON stops (can be found in data.js). Other JS code in that file seems to execute but that function.

Here is the function that gets executed on load:

```
function getAppointments(){
// Update appointments ONLY when online
if(navigator.onLine = true){
    console.log('Application Online.')

    // create appointments table
    createAppTable();
    $.getJSON("http://site.com/OptiQuoteApp/index.php/appointments/download/", function(data) {
        $.each(data,function()
        {
            // Save appointments in database
            updateAppointments(this.quote_id, this.start_date, this.reference, this.first_name+' '+this.last_name, this.comment);
        });
         getAppointmentsList();
    });
}else{
    console.log('Application Offline.')

}
getAppointmentsList();

}
```

Note. I know it says site.com (for security...)

The script gets as far as createAppTable(); then no more.

Any idea anyone?

Billy

Much appreciated

Comment: Did you miss a `==` here: `navigator.onLine = true` ?

Comment: Also, maybe some related info in the comments of https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1579

Comment: Hi Kevin, I realised that after I'd posted it but changing it didn't solve the issue. thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding * under "NETWORK:" in your manifest file. That way anything not specifically cached will get pulled from your site.

```
NETWORK:
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js
js/data.js
js/script.js
*
```

Comment: Thanks Eric that seemed to do it! Does this mean that those files won't have been cached though? I'll need js/data.js and js/script.js when offline? Can I have them in CACHE: and NETWORK: ?

Comment: You should move all of your .js files to the CACHE section.

Comment: I would put data FALLBACK: URLs and NETWORK: sections. For example, if you always return a JSON boolean item "success" and code you could return a simple JSON such as {"success" : false, "code": "offline"}